# Knockouts ko.computed variable does not update when obserable is changed

Tags: knockout.js

How come the computed function this.followButtonText doesn't update ,always shows(Follow), when the observable  this.isFollowing is changed?
      
        $(document).ready(function () {

```
        function AppViewModel() {

            this.toggleIsFollowing = function () {
                this.isFollowing = !this.isFollowing;
                follow();
            };

            this.isFollowing = ko.observable(false);
            this.followButtonText = ko.computed(function () {
                return this.isFollowing ? "Unfollow" : "Follow";
            });
        }

        ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel());


        }

    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An observable is actually a function. To read the current value you need to call it as a function with no arguments like: `this.isFollowing()`.

To set the value of an observable, you need to pass the new value as the first argument.  So, your toggle would look like: `this.isFollowing(!this.isFollowing());`

In your `followButtonText` computed, you would need to call it as a function as well like:

`return this.isFollowing() ? "Unfollow" : "Follow";`

Answer (score 2):

Change this statement:  return this.isFollowing ? "Unfollow" : "Follow";

To this:  return this.isFollowing() ? "Unfollow" : "Follow";

The parenthesis calls it as a function which is needed in order to get the most current value